# SwiftMailer not working, connection could not be established [#0]

Tags: php, silex, swiftmailer, php-openssl

I'm trying to set up a mailer script using Silex and SwiftMailer. However, I haven't managed to get the mail sent so far. When setting `swiftmailer.use_spool` to `false`, I don't get errors but don't receive emails either. When instead flushing the spool transport queue like this...

```
if ($app['mailer.initialized']) {
    $app['swiftmailer.spooltransport']
        ->getSpool()
        ->flushQueue($app['swiftmailer.transport']);
}
```

...I get the following exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host abc.xyz [ #0]'
```

I haven't found any documentation for this exception so far. I'm sure all SMTP settings and credentials are valid (I also tried another host, same problem). I can also ping the host and the port I use is open, and `php_openssl` is enabled.

It looks like it's failing on `Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:269` because `stream_socket_client` returns 0:

```
$this->_stream = @stream_socket_client($host.':'.$this->_params['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
if (false === $this->_stream) {
    throw new Swift_TransportException(
        'Connection could not be established with host '.$this->_params['host'].
        ' ['.$errstr.' #'.$errno.']'
        );
}
```

**Update #1**
I forgot to have a look at the error log, now I see it says:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

So it seems PHP fails to load the php_openssl extension, although `phpinfo()` says the module is enabled? Where should it be located, or how should I get it?

**Update #2**
I believe I may have mistakenly tried to enable the `php_openssl.dll` extension while it's meant for Windows environments. When I remove it, the error is obviously gone from the error log, but the main issue persists. Back to square one..

What could I be doing wrong?